# Is it possible to dynamically generate parts of you web.xml?

Tags: spring, web-applications, web.xml

Is it possible to have entries in your web.xml be dynamically created?

Comment: Gah; why would you want to? What type of information would make sense to be dynamic in the web.xml?

Comment: @DaveNewton I have no idea how servlets are used in the real world. In my e-commerce university module the web.xml file contains ~30 almost identical entries. The only thing which changes is the name since servlet-class = servlet-name = servlet-url, it's tedious to enter new entries and smells bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you mean programmatically defining the contents of your web.xml file - this is possible on containers which support [Servlet 3.0 specs](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315).

.1. It is possible to define your servlets, filters, listeners purely using annotations - `@WebServlet`, `@WebFilter`, `@WebListener`

.2. If you want to register servlets explicitly without web.xml, you can implement a [ServletContainerInitializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html), get a handle of ServletContext and programatically add the servlets, filter etc.

.3. Since you have Spring as a tag, an alternative means to programatically register Spring related front controller(`DispatcherServlet`) and context loader listener is by implementing Spring [WebApplicationInitializer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html), the javadoc in the link has more details.